# When nothing to do, no update in java? That's maybe a bug?

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a game, what stops if the window lost the focus. The problem is when the focus is gained, it doesn't start. I simplyfied that part of my game, here is the code:

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
    static boolean running = true;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main main = new Main();
    main.frameSetup();
    
    while(true)
    {
        if(running)
        {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    }
}

void frameSetup()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(900, 600);
    
    addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
    {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("focus gained");
            running = true;
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent areg0)
        {
            System.out.println("focus lost");
            running = false;
        }
        
    });
    
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

output:

> running
>
> running
>
> ...
>
> focus lost
>
> focus gained

After the "focus gained" I expected to write the lot running again.

The game works, if I put something to the while(true) like a System.out.println:

```
while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("while true");
        if(running)
        {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    }
```

output:

> running
>
> while true
>
> running
>
> while true
>
> ...
>
> focus lost
>
> while true
>
> while true
>
> ...
>
> focus gained
>
> running
>
> while true
>
> running
>
> while true
>
> ...

I don't want to put that System.out.printline or whatever because it uses the processor...

So do you know something to fix this "bug"?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `volatile` to the definition of `running`. I believe the problem is that once `running == false` is detected, it's caching this value and never checking memory again.

Comment: Wow you hit the nail on the head.  I just confirmed @ControlAltDel's answer.  Just add the `volatile` keyword to the variable declaration like he said: `static volatile boolean running = true;`

Comment: Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3

Answer (score 0):

at first look you need syncchronization

- if only one thread is writting your boolean, you can use a volatile 
  (usually you do this to define a stop variable checked in the thread's main loop).
- if you have multiple threads modifying the boolean, you should use synchronization

> READ - MODIFY- WRITE can't be achieved with volatile

https://jorosjavajams.wordpress.com/volatile-vs-synchronized/